# dplyr best practice to filtering on multiple logical columns programmatically

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

## Problem to solve

I need two functions to implement and/or filters on a tibble based on column-indicators (i.e. logical) that could possibly contain missing values. functions' argument should be a character vector of the columns to consider.

## My solution

```r
filter_checked <- function(db, vars = NULL) {
  db %>%
    dplyr::filter(
      dplyr::if_all(dplyr::all_of(vars), ~ !is.na(.x) & .x)
    )
}


filter_or_checked <- function(db, vars = NULL) {
  db %>%
    dplyr::filter(
      dplyr::if_any(dplyr::all_of(vars), ~ !is.na(.x) & .x)
    )
}
```

## Example test to pass

```r
test_that("filter checks", {
  foo <- tibble::tibble(
    id = 1:5,
    a = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    b = c(NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA)
  )


  expect_equal(filter_checked(foo)[["id"]], 1:5)
  expect_equal(filter_checked(foo, "a")[["id"]], 1:2)
  expect_equal(filter_checked(foo, "b")[["id"]], c(2, 4))
  expect_equal(filter_checked(foo, c("a", "b"))[["id"]], 2)

})



test_that("filter_or_checks", {
  foo <- tibble::tibble(
    id = 1:5,
    a = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    b = c(NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA)
  )


  expect_equal(filter_or_checked(foo)[["id"]], integer(0))
  expect_equal(filter_or_checked(foo, "a")[["id"]], 1:2)
  expect_equal(filter_or_checked(foo, "b")[["id"]], c(2, 4))
  expect_equal(filter_or_checked(foo, c("a", "b"))[["id"]], c(1, 2, 4))

})
```

## My question

It seems to me that my functions are quite too intricate. Anyway, I think that this is my lack of knowledge. So, is there a better (i.e., simpler to read/understand/teach) tidyverse solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If find your code interesting.

To answer, a solution I have when you have many booleans (at least three or more) is to convert all of them in one column with 0 (FALSE) and 1 (TRUE), for instance for five booleans, it will look like that:

```
00000
01000
11111
01001
11110
```

Then:

- to know if all booleans are TRUE, you can count how many '1' there are in each cell and ask to have as many '1' as column number
- to know if at least one column is TRUE just search string '1'

In my case I haven't take into account missing value. But you could recode them 2 for instance.

Finally this involves more data preparation and a less complicated function after that (because you are not playing with multiples booleans but only one character string).

the code would be something like:

```
library(dplyr)

# Prepare data, from your data 
foo <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  a = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  b = c(NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA),
  d_bis = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  e_bis = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  f_bis = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
) %>% 
  mutate(a_bis = a, b_bis = b) %>% # copy columns to test
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('_bis')), as.integer) %>% # convert logicals to integers
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('_bis')), tidyr::replace_na, replace = 2) %>% # replace NA with 2
  mutate(af_bis = paste0(a_bis, b_bis, d_bis, e_bis, f_bis))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 9
     id a     b     d_bis e_bis f_bis a_bis b_bis af_bis
  <int> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 TRUE  NA        1     1     1     1     2 12111 
2     2 TRUE  TRUE      1     1     1     1     1 11111 
3     3 FALSE NA        0     0     0     0     2 02000 
4     4 FALSE TRUE      0     0     0     0     1 01000 
5     5 FALSE NA        0     0     0     0     2 02000
```

```
# list rows where at least one is TRUE
foo %>% 
  filter(grepl('1', af_bis))

# list rows where all columns are TRUE
foo %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_count(af_bis, '1') == 5L)

# list where at least one column is TRUE only if all columns are not missing
foo %>% 
  filter(grepl('1', af_bis) & ! grepl('2', af_bis))
```

Comment: That way, variables selected for filtering are fixed _a priori_ and hard-coded in the preprocessed dataset. I need them like a filtering function's parameter. Including all the preprocessing into the, e.g., `filter_or_checked()` body, would be way too complex (and risky). Moreover `mutate_at` is currently superseded.